# Importing many google fonts in a webpage

Tags: css, http, browser, fonts, stylesheet

For example, let's say I import 50 fonts like this:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora|Droid+Sans|Roboto...");

.font-lora{
   font-family: "Loral";
}

.font-droid-sans{
   font-family: "Droid Sans";
}

.font-roboto{
   font-family: "Roboto";
}

...
```

But only 2 or 3 of those classes are used in the page.

My question is if there are any non obvious side effects of importing that many fonts on a webpage, from which only 2-3 will be actually used.

From what I understand browsers only request the fonts when there are elements on the page that have styles with them. Right?

I'm doing this as part of an interface that allows users to pick fonts, and I noticed that changing classes is much smoother than switching stylesheets

Comment: Should this be on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: What framework are you using? The primary difference you'll see is the time it takes for a client to load you page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes/No. IE will load them load all because you are using the @import the browser will reach out and grab that file.  Do not load fonts that you are not using as those are extra requests.  Here is what [google says](http://googlewebfonts.blogspot.jp/2010/09/optimizing-use-of-google-font-api.html):

> This may seem obvious, but if you don't actually use a font, don't request it in the API. You might miss this if you do your testing in Firefox or Chrome, which only load the font files needed to render the text on the page. Internet Explorer, by contrast, loads all the fonts requested, even if they’re not actually used.

Also you may be better off downloading all those fonts then loading them all so they are on the server at request.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @BuiltInOneDay

What happens when you slap a fancy new @font-face custom web font into your CSS? As it turns out—not much. Just including a @font-face block doesn’t actually initiate a download of the remote font file from the server in almost all browsers (except IE8).

```
/* Does not download */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansregular';
    src: /* This article does not cover @font-face syntax */;
}
```

So, how does one go about initiating a font download? Peep your eyes on this source:

```
<!-- Initiates download in Firefox, IE 9+ -->
<div style="font-family: open_sansregular"></div>

<!-- Initiates download in Chrome, Safari (WebKit/Blink et al) -->
<div style="font-family: open_sansregular">Content.</div>
```

This means that WebKit and Blink are smart enough to know that even if a node exists in the document that uses our new font-family but the node is empty—the font does not download. This is great!

What if we create the nodes dynamically in JavaScript?

```
/* Does not download */
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.style.fontFamily = 'open_sansregular';

/* Initiates download in Firefox, IE 9+ */
document.body.appendChild(el);

/* Initiates download in WebKit/Blink */
el.innerHTML = 'Content.';
```

All but IE8 wait until the new node has been appended into the document (is not detached) and as previously mentioned, WebKit/Blink browsers even wait until the node has text content.

Now we know what @font-face got right. Now let’s get our hands dirty.

...

**Read the source by Zach Leatherman from Opera for more: https://dev.opera.com/articles/better-font-face/**